# IOS : fill a tableview with tableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How can I fill a `UITableView` with some `UITableViewCell` (customized)?

Comment: I think you should elaborate your question a little bit more, otherwise it will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the tutorials -

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/